# Jackson date format with @JsonFormat?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialize certain Calendar fields of a POJO with a specific format.

with no annotations, fields like this:

```
private Calendar timestamp1;
private Calendar timestamp2;
```

produce JSON like this:

```
{ ..., timestamp1: 1402402106000, timestamp2: 1402488595000, ... }
```

I would to add a field formatted as a string as it actually represents a Day as a 24-hour unit, not a specific instant of time.  But when I add a new field with an annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Calendar oneDay;
```

I was hoping to get JSON like this:

```
{ ..., timestamp1: 1402402106000, timestamp2: 1402488595000, oneDay: "2014-06-12", ... }
```

Instead, I got a the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
    Cannot format given Object as a Date 
    (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["data"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]-myPojo["oneDay"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Jackson 2.2.0

Comment: Show the line where you're storing the "oneDay" into `Date`.

Comment: All of the fields are read out of a database

Comment: Support for `@JsonFormat` with dates was added at a later point (2.3.3 I think); so you may want to try Jackson 2.4.0.

Comment: I had the same problem and could solve it with updating to 2.4.2

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I've used: `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")`

That works for me.